# I am starting with assembly whats th wrong in my code and how to print the result

Tags: assembly, division, emu8086

The error is it divides by zero, but I don't think that's the problem

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

x db 6
z dw ?
.code
main proc
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov ah,2
mov al,x
add al,3
div ah
int 21h

main endp
end ma
```

Comment: Don't use `ah` as the divisor. `DIV r/m8` divides `ax` by the operand. Since you've set `ah=2` and `al=3`, you're dividing 0x203 by 2, giving a quotient of 0x101, which is too large to fit in 8 bits, hence the Divide Error exception.

Comment: i don't get it 
how should it be ??

Comment: Set `ah` to 0 prior to the division, and use some other register as the divisor. In this particular case you could also replace the division by `shr al,1` since that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your help